# How to use Lazy_LPC filter (Z Transform) make prediction

Tags: python, transform, prediction, lpc

I want to use LPC(Linear Predictive Coding) in Python to predict the next value of some data.
I used audiolazy package and I got the Z Filter equation like this:
1 - 0.625 * z^-1 + 0.25 * z^-2 + 0.125 * z^-3

After that, I want to use this filter to make a prediction about the next value
But I am not sure what to be the input of this filter.

I found the definition of the A Filter object is **Zfilter(seq, memory=None, zero=0.0)**

- **seq** – Any iterable to be seem as the input stream for the filter.
- **memory** – Might be an iterable or a callable. Generally, as a iterable, the first needed elements from this input will be used directly as the memory (not the last ones!), and as a callable, it will be called with the size as the only positional argument, and should return an iterable. If None (default), memory is initialized with zeros.
- **zero** – Value to fill the memory, when needed, and to be seem as previous input when there’s a delay. Defaults to 0.0.
- **Returns**:  A Stream that have the data from the input sequence
  filtered.

I have 2 questions here:

1. I have an OriginData array: d=[1,2,3,4], and I want to predict the next value. Is it correct to put inputDta=[1,2,3,4,0] as input to Z filter?
2. I don't understand the memory parameter. Could you please explain it with simple examples?

Here is my code:

```
from audiolazy import *
d=[-0.94,  0.18, -0.34,0.57, -0.36,  1.23] # this is the origin data
acdata = acorr(d)                          # auto correlation
filt=levinson_durbin(acdata,3)             #obtain Z Filter
p=list(filt([ 0.57, -0.36,  1.23, 0]))     # [ 0.57, -0.36,  1.23, 0] is the input data to the 
                                             filter, I want to use 3 past data to predict the next 
                                             one


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
d.append(p[-1])
plt.plot((adjdata['delta'][-7:]).values)
plt.plot(d)
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG6at.png)